# Moving through pictures by fading in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, fade

I have some pictures and I want to navigate through them by clicking a button in my HTML. I need the effect to occur when the user clicks - I do not want to reload my page. Is there any Javascript or CSS that can help?
I mean by pressing the "Next" button the next image can softly fade into the screen.

Comment: Google it! there are 100's of this available.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka thanks dude I did and I found some nice circus horses.(kidding) then I tried "carousels java" and found some web sites. let me check them also.

Comment: @SVS I searched before i asked and i did not find a simple solution. so i asked here.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka "carousels" is also JQuery. I am really noob on that

Comment: Not a problem..! You don't have to do anything. Just download the script.You can link it to your page following some simple instructions provided in the downloaded folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `div` like this:

```
<div id="yourDivId" >
    <img id="image_1_Id" class="" src="image_1.png" />
    <img id="image_2_Id" class="transparent" src="image_2.png" />
</div>
```

Insert this code to your css file:

```
#yourDivId img.transparent 
{
    opacity:0;
}
#yourDivId img
{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

And add this script to your javascript file or html head script:

```
function btnClicked(){
    document.getElementById("image_1_Id").className += "transparent";
    document.getElementById("image_2_Id").className = "";
}
```

Check this site http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ for more examples!

Comment: Thanks Dude. this worked for me fine. simple and useful. and thanks for giving me the hole code.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery Cycle. It has a bunch of available transitions and you can set it up with external previous/next controls.

Main plugin page: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Demo using previous/next links: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Comment: thanks. I am very new in JQuery. I will try to understand the demos.